# Language selector for Apache Solr search form

Tags: 7, search, i18n-l10n

How can I do something like this with Apache Solr in Drupal 7?

[image: screenshot]

This will be the front page of my site, and depending on the language the user chooses, he will be redirected to the language-specific subdomain of my site with the respective search results:

- en.mysite.com/search/search=type+here&lang=en
- es.mysite.com/search/search=type+here&lang=es
- jp.mysite.com/search/search=type+here&lang=jp

Of course, only results with the user's language should be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Solr Multilingual](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_multilingual) module should do what you appear to want.

> ... provides a way to offer language-specific searches for different
>   languages at once on multilingual websites ...

I'm using the not-yet-released 7x dev version with some success.  A registered-user's primary language selection, or override from a drop-down in the site-wide menu sets a $var which I carry through to the Solr search module, language-specific content, and Drupal language overlays for standard markup, etc.