# Apache Solr Search show only currrent user language

Tags: 7, search, i18n-l10n

I'm using Apache Solr Search Integration to do the searching on our website, works great except i get results for all the language on the site instead of only the one the user is currently using.

Is there a way to show only nodes that are in the current users language? Either filter it out of the results by a simple check or directly in the query?

I was hoping there would be a hook to alter the results before the pager is created, i got as for as filtering out the other language in hook_apachesolr_search_page_alter() but thats to late, then you get a pager for 3 pages with only one result.

I also tried Apache Solr Multilingual but that doesn't seem the work really well at the moment for 7.x.

Comment: Does http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/4311/6286 solve your problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is to implement [hook_apachesolr_query_alter()](http://drupalcode.org/project/apachesolr.git/blob/d7bd3ee8d0aadd5c6bbf9e649c813e7edda2f66c:/apachesolr.api.php#l161) to automatically filter on the current language. In a custom module called "mymodule", the code snippet would look similar to the following:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_apachesolr_query_alter()
 */
function mymodule_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
  global $language;
  $query->addFilter("ss_language", $language->language);
}
```

Comment: The above piece of code solves this issue:):) Thanks Chris:)